# AMPL to JuMP (Julia)

Tags: optimization, julia, mathematical-optimization, modeling, julia-jump

I need to transform a AMPL code to JuMP.

```
param f;

set R := 1..N;
set R_OK := 1..M;
set V := 1..N;

param tMax;
set T := 1..tMax;

var primary{R,V}, binary;
var SendPrepReq{T,R,V}, binary;
```

"param f" would be an int. The varibles I know how to do. But what about the sets? What is its equivalent in JuMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most relevant pieces of documentation may be the [Quickstart guide](https://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/stable/quickstart/) to get the basics of how JuMP works.

For your example, you can just declare your parameters directly:

```
using JuMP

# declare some parameters
f = 3
N = 10
M = 5
R = 1:N
V = 1:N
R_OK = 1:M

Tmax = 33
T = 1:Tmax

# create the model
m = Model()
# add variables
@variable(m, primary[R,V], Bin)
@variable(m, SendPrepReq[T,R,V], Bin)
```

**EDIT**

One might want to provide parameters independently from the model declaration as in AMLP. The most straightforward way in Julia will be to build and solve the model in a function taking the problem parameters in argument:

```
function build_model(f, N, M, Tmax)
    R = 1:N
    V = 1:N
    R_OK = 1:M
    T = 1:Tmax

    # create the model
    m = Model()
    # add variables
    @variable(m, primary[R,V], Bin)
    @variable(m, SendPrepReq[T,R,V], Bin)

    return (m, primary, SendPrepReq)
end
```

Comment: parameters are just simple variables as in other programming languages. If you want to given them values later, the simplest way will be to put the optimization in a function with the parameters as arguments

Comment: Would it be right to say that " var prepReqSendPerNodeAndView{R,V}, integer, >= 0; "  would be " @varible(m, prepReqSendPerNodeAndView[R,V] >=0, Int) "

Comment: Yes that's correct, watch out for the typo in `@variable`

Comment: In the AMPL code, there is a parte called "Time zero constraints", and they are like:
"initializeSendPrepareReq{i in R, v in V}: SendPrepReq[1, i, v] = 0;" and  

"initializeRecvCV{i in R, j in R, v in V}: RecvCV[1, i, j, v] = 0;"

I got some ideia from the guide, but I don't know how to do these.

Comment: That would correspond to fixing a variable to a value, which is done in JuMP with the fix function: JuMP.fix(SendPrepReq[1, i, v], 0)

Comment: Thanks, but didn't you forget to define "i" and "v" before the fixing? In the original code says "i in R" and "v in "V" before the SendPrepReq[1, i, v] = 0;